# How to disable possible stack smashing protection (EIP is not being overwritten, EBP is)

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, buffer-overflow

I'm trying to figure out how stash smashing is carried out step by step. I have already used Google to no avail, I still don't know why my EIP is not being overwritten. I have this example program:

```
 1 #include <stdio.h>
 2 #include <string.h>
 3 
 4 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 5 {
 6     char buf[10];
 7 
 8     strcpy(buf, argv[1]);
 9     printf("Done.\n");
10     return 0;
11     
12 }
```

It's compiled with

```
gcc -g -o prog main.c
```

When I put a lot of AAAAAA's I get SEGV and the register EBP (and also argc and argv addresses are overwritten:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x08048472 in main (argc=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x41414141>, argv=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x41414145>)
    at main.c:12
12  }
(gdb) info reg
eax            0x0  0
ecx            0x41414141   1094795585
edx            0xb7fbb878   -1208240008
ebx            0xb7fba000   -1208246272
esp            0x4141413d   0x4141413d
ebp            0x41414141   0x41414141
esi            0x0  0
edi            0x0  0
eip            0x8048472    0x8048472 <main+71>
eflags         0x10282  [ SF IF RF ]
cs             0x73 115
ss             0x7b 123
ds             0x7b 123
es             0x7b 123
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x33 51
```

I thought that EIP is just below EBP, but it still has the address from main function. Here's the disassembly of main:

```
(gdb) disass main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0804842b <+0>: lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx
   0x0804842f <+4>: and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   0x08048432 <+7>: pushl  -0x4(%ecx)
   0x08048435 <+10>:    push   %ebp
   0x08048436 <+11>:    mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x08048438 <+13>:    push   %ecx
   0x08048439 <+14>:    sub    $0x14,%esp
   0x0804843c <+17>:    mov    %ecx,%eax
   0x0804843e <+19>:    mov    0x4(%eax),%eax
   0x08048441 <+22>:    add    $0x4,%eax
   0x08048444 <+25>:    mov    (%eax),%eax
   0x08048446 <+27>:    sub    $0x8,%esp
   0x08048449 <+30>:    push   %eax
   0x0804844a <+31>:    lea    -0x12(%ebp),%eax
   0x0804844d <+34>:    push   %eax
   0x0804844e <+35>:    call   0x80482f0 <strcpy@plt>
   0x08048453 <+40>:    add    $0x10,%esp
   0x08048456 <+43>:    sub    $0xc,%esp
   0x08048459 <+46>:    push   $0x8048510
   0x0804845e <+51>:    call   0x8048300 <puts@plt>
   0x08048463 <+56>:    add    $0x10,%esp
   0x08048466 <+59>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0804846b <+64>:    mov    -0x4(%ebp),%ecx
   0x0804846e <+67>:    leave  
   0x0804846f <+68>:    lea    -0x4(%ecx),%esp
=> 0x08048472 <+71>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

Now I'm in the process of figuring out the assembler instructions one by one, but I don't see the moment where EIP is loaded with a return address from the stack just after `strcpy` finishes. I tried the `-fno-stack-protector` but it didn't change a thing. What could be the reason for this?

EDIT:

OK, I'll try to go over it step by step, please correct me where I'm wrong

```
   # Just below the sp are argc and argv and the sp points to the address
   # where RET will be stored
   # This one moves the address of argc (which is on the stack) to $ecx 
   0x0804842b <+0>: lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx
   # Move stack pointer down for alignment
   0x0804842f <+4>: and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   # Push the value to which $sp pointed to before alignment 
   # It is never used - correct me if I'm wrong  
   0x08048432 <+7>: pushl  -0x4(%ecx)
   # Push last used base pointer value (and start creating another frame)
   0x08048435 <+10>:    push   %ebp
   # Set current position sp as bp - I think here the main body starts
   0x08048436 <+11>:    mov    %esp,%ebp
   # Push the address of argc - it's later used for calculating 
   # the address of argv[1]. 
   0x08048438 <+13>:    push   %ecx
   # Make some space on the stack (20 bytes - 5 words - first two I'm 
   # sure for what (alignment and not used here return value?) 
   # another 3 for buffer[10]
   0x08048439 <+14>:    sub    $0x14,%esp
   # Move argc address to $eax
   0x0804843c <+17>:    mov    %ecx,%eax
   # Move argv address to $eax
   0x0804843e <+19>:    mov    0x4(%eax),%eax
   # Move past argv - $eax should now point to pointer to first 
   # argument string
   0x08048441 <+22>:    add    $0x4,%eax
   # Move the address of the parameter string to $eax
   0x08048444 <+25>:    mov    (%eax),%eax
   # Make space for 2 words 
   # (probably alignment and return value from strcpy)
   0x08048446 <+27>:    sub    $0x8,%esp
   # Push the parameter address
   0x08048449 <+30>:    push   %eax
   # Get the address of the local buffer
   0x0804844a <+31>:    lea    -0x12(%ebp),%eax
   # Push it
   0x0804844d <+34>:    push   %eax
   # Call strcpy
   0x0804844e <+35>:    call   0x80482f0 <strcpy@plt>
   # Remove 4 words - 2 for arguments and 2 for return + alignment
   0x08048453 <+40>:    add    $0x10,%esp
   # Make space for 3 words - alignment + return value
   0x08048456 <+43>:    sub    $0xc,%esp
   # Push the printf argument address (the string address)
   0x08048459 <+46>:    push   $0x8048510
   # Call printf
   0x0804845e <+51>:    call   0x8048300 <puts@plt>
   # Remove 4 words - 1 for parameter and previous 3
   0x08048463 <+56>:    add    $0x10,%esp
   # Reset 0x0 just because
   0x08048466 <+59>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   # Load previously saved address of argc
   0x0804846b <+64>:    mov    -0x4(%ebp),%ecx
   # not sure about that leave...
   0x0804846e <+67>:    leave  
   # Reload $esp starting value
   0x0804846f <+68>:    lea    -0x4(%ecx),%esp
   # Pop the RET address - this one should be changed to 
   # pointer to malicious code
=> 0x08048472 <+71>:    ret
```

1. Is the value in line +7 unnecessary? I don't see any use for it, so why is it stored?
2. In some places sp moves more than it has to - is it due to alignment? (e.g. line +14)
3. Is my conclusion over line +71 correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disclaimer:  I am using gcc-4.8.3 on a Windows 7 system with gnuwin32 installed.  Windows doesn't appear to have  ASLR enabled by default, so I get reproducible memory addresses when I run this program which makes life a bit easier.  Also, if you follow this the memory address you get will, in all probability, be different.

Now consider this program:

```
#include <string.h>

void copyinput(char* input)
{
    char buf[10];
    strcpy(buf, input);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int a = 5;
    copyinput(argv[1]);
    a = 7;

    return 0;
}
```

which we can compile with this command line:

```
gcc -g -ansi -pedantic -Wall overflow2.c -o overflow
```

and then run the program under gdb.

We place a break point at `main' and set the command line argument to "AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCC" and note the following:

1. first note the disassembly of main:

   ```
      0x0040157a <+0>:     push   %ebp
      0x0040157b <+1>:     mov    %esp,%ebp
   => 0x0040157d <+3>:     and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
      0x00401580 <+6>:     sub    $0x20,%esp
      0x00401583 <+9>:     call   0x401fd0 <__main>
      0x00401588 <+14>:    movl   $0x5,0x1c(%esp)
      0x00401590 <+22>:    mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
      0x00401593 <+25>:    add    $0x4,%eax
      0x00401596 <+28>:    mov    (%eax),%eax
      0x00401598 <+30>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
      0x0040159b <+33>:    call   0x401560 <copyinput>
      0x004015a0 <+38>:    movl   $0x7,0x1c(%esp)
      0x004015a8 <+46>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
      0x004015ad <+51>:    leave  
      0x004015ae <+52>:    ret    
      0x004015af <+53>:    nop
   ```

   what we are interested in here is the address of the next
   instruction after we call `copyinput`.  This will be the value of
   *eip* that gets pushed on the stack when control flow is passed to
   `copyinput`.
2. lets look at the registers:

   ```
   (gdb) info reg
   eax            0x1  1
   ecx            0x752c1162   1965822306
   edx            0xa02080 10494080
   ebx            0x2  2
   esp            0x28fea0 0x28fea0
   ebp            0x28fec8 0x28fec8
   esi            0xa01858 10491992
   edi            0x1f 31
   eip            0x401590 0x401590 <main+22>
   eflags         0x202    [ IF ]
   cs             0x23 35
   ss             0x2b 43
   ds             0x2b 43
   es             0x2b 43
   fs             0x53 83
   gs             0x2b 43
   ```

   we are interested in *esp* and *ebp* from the above.  Remember that *ebp*
   should also get pushed onto the stack during the function call to
   `copyinput`.
3. Single-step to the invocation of `copyinput` and then step into that
   function.  At this point, look at the registers (before the call to
   `strcpy`) again:

   ```
   (gdb) info reg
   eax            0x9218b0 9574576
   ecx            0x752c1162   1965822306
   edx            0x922080 9576576
   ebx            0x2  2
   esp            0x28fe70 0x28fe70
   ebp            0x28fe98 0x28fe98
   esi            0x921858 9574488
   edi            0x1f 31
   eip            0x401566 0x401566 <copyinput+6>
   eflags         0x202    [ IF ]
   cs             0x23 35
   ss             0x2b 43
   ds             0x2b 43
   es             0x2b 43
   fs             0x53 83
   gs             0x2b 43
   ```

   What we can see here is that the stack frame for `copyinput` is from
   0x28fe70 to 0x28fe98, and referring back to point (2) we can see
   that the stack frame for `main` is based at 0x28fec8.
4. We can examine the stack from 0x28fe70 to 0x28fec8 (a total of 88
   bytes) like this:

   ```
       (gdb) x/88xb 0x28fe70

       0x28fe70:   0x50    0x15    0x40    0x00    0xdc    0x00    0x00    0x00
       0x28fe78:   0xff    0xff    0xff    0xff    0x30    0x60    0x44    0x00
       0x28fe80:   0x03    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x8c    0xfe    0x28    0x00
       0x28fe88:   0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x8f    0x17    0x40    0x00
       0x28fe90:   0x50    0x1f    0x40    0x00    0x1c    0x50    0x40    0x00
       0x28fe98:   0xc8    0xfe    0x28    0x00    0xa0    0x15    0x40    0x00
       0x28fea0:   0xb0    0x18    0x92    0x00    0x00    0x50    0x40    0x00
       0x28fea8:   0x88    0xff    0x28    0x00    0xae    0x1f    0x40    0x00
       0x28feb0:   0x50    0x1f    0x40    0x00    0x60    0x00    0x00    0x40
       0x28feb8:   0x1f    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x05    0x00    0x00    0x00
       0x28fec0:   0x58    0x17    0x92    0x00    0x1f    0x00    0x00    0x00
   ```

   The raw memory dump is not very easy to read, so lets collapse the
   bytes into words, and convert the byte order into big-endian, and we
   can see where certain values are located at:

   ```
   0x28fe70: 0x00401550  <- esp for `copyinput`
             0x000000dc
   0x28fe78: 0xffffffff
             0x00446030
   0x28fe80: 0x00000003    
             0x0028fe8c
   0x28fe88: 0x00000000    
             0x0040178f
   0x28fe90: 0x00401f50    
             0x0040501c
   0x28fe98: 0x0028fec8 <- stored *ebp* for `main``s stack frame
             0x004015a0 <- stored *eip*, 
   0x28fea0: 0x009218b0 <- esp for `main``s stack frame    
             0x00405000
   ```

   So from this we can see that the stored *eip* is located on the
   stack at address 0x28fe9C.  From this you can see that *eip* gets pushed onto the stack first then *ebp* get pushed on the stack.
5. Now single stepping till after the call to string copy and examining
   memory again shows:

   ```
   (gdb) x/88xb 0x28fe70
   0x28fe70:   0x86    0xfe    0x28    0x00    0xb0    0x18    0x92    0x00
   0x28fe78:   0xff    0xff    0xff    0xff    0x30    0x60    0x44    0x00
   0x28fe80:   0x03    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x8c    0xfe    0x41    0x41
   0x28fe88:   0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
   0x28fe90:   0x42    0x42    0x42    0x42    0x42    0x42    0x42    0x42
   0x28fe98:   0x42    0x42    0x43    0x43    0x43    0x43    0x43    0x43
   0x28fea0:   0x43    0x43    0x43    0x43    0x00    0x50    0x40    0x00
   0x28fea8:   0x88    0xff    0x28    0x00    0xae    0x1f    0x40    0x00
   0x28feb0:   0x50    0x1f    0x40    0x00    0x60    0x00    0x00    0x40
   0x28feb8:   0x1f    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x05    0x00    0x00    0x00
   0x28fec0:   0x58    0x17    0x92    0x00    0x1f    0x00    0x00    0x00
   ```

   and we can see that both the stored values of *ebp* and *eip* have been
   clobbered on the stack.  Now when we return from `copyinput` which
   will pop the value for *eip* (which is now 0x43434343) and *ebp* (which
   is now 0x43434242) off the stack and attempt to execute the
   instruction at 0x43434343; which will obviously generate an
   exception.

The main thrust of a stack attack like this would be to arrange it so that we overwrite *eip* with a valid value of our choosing.  For example, consider the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void copyinput(char* input)
{
   char buf[10];
   strcpy(buf, input);
}

void testinput()
{
    printf("we should never see this\n");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int a = 5;
    copyinput(argv[1]);
    a = 7;

   return 0;
}
```

The function `testinput` is never called.  However if we can overwrite the return address in `copyinput` with the value of 0x0040157a (which is the location of `testinput` on my machine) we would be able to cause that function to execute.

=================================================================================
answers for questions made in the comments:

Not sure what OS/compiler you are using.  I took your sample program compiled it using gcc-4.8.3 on a Windows 7 box.  My disassembly for main looks like this:

```
(gdb) disass main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x00401560 <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x00401561 <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x00401563 <+3>: and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   0x00401566 <+6>: sub    $0x20,%esp
   0x00401569 <+9>: call   0x401fc0 <__main>
```

This is the preamble for main in which we are setting up the stack frame for main.  We push the base-pointer of the previous stack frame (from some function provided by the run-time library), then move the the base pointer to where the stack point is.  Next with we adjust *esp* to make it evenly divisible by 16 and then we subtract 32 bytes (0x20) from *esp* (remember that the stack grows down, so we now have some space that main is going to use.

The common pattern of `push %ebp`, `mov %esp, %ebp` and then `sub xxx, %esp` is a common preamble for a function.

Lets try to find where things are located in memory, shall we.  In gdb we can do the following:

```
(gdb) x/16xb &argv[0]
0xa31830:   0x58    0x18    0xa3    0x00    0x98    0x18    0xa3    0x00
0xa31838:   0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0xab    0xab    0xab    0xab
```

Which is what we expect, two 32-bit pointers followed by a null terminator.  So argv[0] is located at 0x00a31858 and argv[1](http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/debugging/linuxProgramStartup.html) is located at 0x00a31898; which can be seen by examining the memor at these two locations:

```
(gdb) x/20cb 0x00a31858
0xa31858:   100 'd' 58 ':'  92 '\\' 117 'u' 115 's' 101 'e' 114 'r' 115 's'
0xa31860:   92 '\\' 103 'g' 104 'h' 117 'u' 98 'b'  101 'e' 114 'r' 92 '\\'
0xa31868:   71 'G'  78 'N'  85 'U'  72 'H'
(gdb) x/20xb 0x00a31898
0xa31898:   0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0xa318a0:   0x41    0x41    0x00    0xab    0xab    0xab    0xab    0xab
0xa318a8:   0xab    0xab    0xab    0xfe
```

We can find out where our buffer is located but doing the following in GDB:

```
(gdb) print $esp
$4 = (void *) 0x28fea0
(gdb) print $ebp
$5 = (void *) 0x28fec8
(gdb) x/40xb $esp
0x28fea0:   0xb6    0xfe    0x28    0x00    0x98    0x18    0xa3    0x00
0x28fea8:   0x88    0xff    0x28    0x00    0x9e    0x1f    0x40    0x00
0x28feb0:   0x40    0x1f    0x40    0x00    0x60    0x00    0x41    0x41
0x28feb8:   0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41
0x28fec0:   0x00    0x17    0xa3    0x00    0x0b    0x00    0x00    0x00
```

So we can see that our buffer starts at 0x28feb6

Now that we have that out of the way, lets looks at the next section of our code, which should be setting up for the call to `strcpy`:

```
   0x0040156e <+14>:    mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
   0x00401571 <+17>:    add    $0x4,%eax
   0x00401574 <+20>:    mov    (%eax),%eax
   0x00401576 <+22>:    mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
   0x0040157a <+26>:    lea    0x16(%esp),%eax
   0x0040157e <+30>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x00401581 <+33>:    call   0x402748 <strcpy>
```

As a reminder, in AT&T assembly syntax the address operand looks like this:

```
displacement(base register, offset register, scalar multiplier)
```

which is equivalent to the intel syntax:

```
[base register + displacement + offset register * scalar multiplier]
```

So with that,

```
   0x0040156e <+14>:    mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
   0x00401571 <+17>:    add    $0x4,%eax
   0x00401574 <+20>:    mov    (%eax),%eax
   0x00401576 <+22>:    mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
```

We add 0x0C to our current base pointer which give a value of 0x28FED4, and we then copy what that contained at that memory address to *eax*.  By using GDB, we can find out that the four bytes located at `0x08FEC4` is `0x00a31830` which is the address of argv[0].  Adding four to *eax* causes *eax* to now point to argv[1](http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/debugging/linuxProgramStartup.html).  The next two instructions effectively move the address of argv[1](http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/debugging/linuxProgramStartup.html) to four bytes above *esp*.

```
   0x0040157a <+26>:    lea    0x16(%esp),%eax
   0x0040157e <+30>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
```

Continuing along, we increment *esp* by 0x16 (which gives us 0x28FEB6, which we have previously determined to be where `buf[10]` is located.  We then move this value to where *esp* is at.  At this time, our stack now looks like:

```
           ~            ~
           |            |
           +------------+
0x28fea4   | 0x00a31898 |    remember that this is the address of argv[1][0]
           +------------+
0x28fea0   | 0x0028feb6 |    remember that this is the address of buf[0]
           +------------+
```

Which makes sense given that the function prototype for `strcpy` which is:

```
    char*  strcpy(char* dst, const char* src);
```

And that typically, arguments are pushed onto the stack from right to left, so we would expect that the `src` gets pushed on first and then `dst` would get pushed on second.  So instead of just pushing the arguments onto the stack, the compiler set aside enough space so that it could load the required values at the correct place.  So everything is in place and we can now call `strcpy`.

The next few instructions just set up the call to `printf` (well actually `puts`),  we need to move the address of the string "Done.\n" onto the stack and then call `puts`:

```
   0x00401586 <+38>:    movl   $0x404024,(%esp)
   0x0040158d <+45>:    call   0x402750 <puts>
```

Finally, we move the return value into *eax* (which is the register that normally contains the return value from a function) and then we exit `main`.

```
   0x00401592 <+50>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x00401597 <+55>:    leave  
   0x00401598 <+56>:    ret
```

Not sure if I answered all of your questions, but I think I did.  Also I hope I didn't screw up the analysis too much, I don't normally do that in depth analysis of assembly or use AT&T syntax.

=============== edit2 ===================================

Three remaining questions:

> Is the value in line +7 unnecessary? I don't see any use for it, so
>   why is it stored?

Your analysis that we are pushing the original, un-aligned value of *esp* appears correct.  My hunch is that in the first few lines of your disassembly we 
are looking at special start-up code for main.  Remember that there was a stack frame on the stack prior to the creation of the stack frame for main.  You may want to take a look at [this link](http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/debugging/linuxProgramStartup.html) to see what the normal start-up order of a program under Linux is.

My hunch is that we need to preserve the unmodified value of *esp* so that we can restore an earlier stack frame to its correct location.

> In some places sp moves more than it has to - is it due to alignment?
>   (e.g. line +14)

I would make the analysis that these lines are where we are actually setting up the stack frame for main.  In `main+14` we are subtracting 20 bytes from *esp* so we are allocating 20 bytes for use by our main function.  We can argue that 12 of those bytes are used by our buffer (remember that there probably will be two bytes of padding at the end of our buffer so that the next value stored on the stack will be at a 32-bit word boundary).

```
   0x08048435 <+10>:    push   %ebp
   0x08048436 <+11>:    mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x08048438 <+13>:    push   %ecx
   0x08048439 <+14>:    sub    $0x14,%esp
```

So, I would claim that `main+10` through `main+14` are the normal function prolog

> Is my conclusion over line +71 correct?

Yes.  At this point we need to have overwritten the stored *eip* on the stack and this will cause the RET instruction to read our value.  The following description of the RET instruction is taken from [from here](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html) (actually this page has a good deal of information on assembly it is well worth reading.  The only down side is that this page uses the Intel syntax and you have been presenting AT&T syntax.)

> call, ret — Subroutine call and return
>
> These instructions implement a subroutine call and return. The call 
>   instruction first pushes the current code location onto the
>   hardware supported stack in memory (see the push instruction for
>   details), and then performs an unconditional jump to the code location
>   indicated by the label operand. Unlike the simple jump instructions,
>   the call instruction saves the location to return to when the
>   subroutine completes.
>
> The ret instruction implements a subroutine return mechanism. This instruction > first pops a code location off the hardware supported
>   in-memory stack (see the pop instruction for details). It then
>   performs an unconditional jump to the retrieved code location.
>
> ```
> Syntax
> call <label>
> ret
> ```

Additional information on the LEAVE instruction (used at `main+67`) is (taken from [here](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_154.html)):

> Releases the stack frame set up by an earlier ENTER instruction. The
>   LEAVE instruction copies the frame pointer (in the EBP register) into
>   the stack pointer register (ESP), which releases the stack space
>   allocated to the stack frame. The old frame pointer (the frame pointer
>   for the calling procedure that was saved by the ENTER instruction) is
>   then popped from the stack into the EBP register, restoring the
>   calling procedure's stack frame.
>
> A RET instruction is commonly executed following a LEAVE instruction
>   to return program control to the calling procedure.
>
> See "Procedure Calls for Block-Structured Languages" in Chapter 6 of
>   the IA-32 Intel Architecture Software Developer's Manual, Volume 1,
>   for detailed information on the use of the ENTER and LEAVE
>   instructions.

*N.B.* it is possible to change the flavor of the disassembly emitted by GDB by 
using the following commands:

```
set disassembly-flavor att
set disassembly-flavor intel
show disassembly-flavor
```

The third command shows what the current flavor is.

*PS* I second Jesters comment in his answer below.  Moving the actual vulnerable code off to a function rather then in main will make the analysis easier as you don't have to deal with the weirdness of the alignment of main and the unique prolog and epilog for main.  Once you've gotten a handle on this type of stack exploitation you can then go back and work through an example where the vulnerability is in main.

*PPS* working on a Linux system you may also run into ASLR issues, in that every time you run a program things are a different memory locations, so the offsets between stack frames and stack frame locations will change.  You can use the following short program (taken from The Shellcoder's Handbook: Discovering and Exploiting Security Holes by Chris Anley, *et.al*) to see if ASLR is an issue

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    unsigned long find_start(void)
    {
        __asm__("movl %esp, %eax");
    }

    int main()
    {
        printf("0x%x\n", find_start());
        return (0);
    }
```

Run the program several times, if the output differs you have some version of ASLR running.  It will make your life more difficult, but not insurmountable

Comment: Wow, thanks for taking the time to write all this. It helped a bit, but can you help me with the edit? I'm not sure what certain lines do.

Comment: @Bart, sure what lines do you need explained?

Comment: I'm in the process of rewriting my edit, made some mistakes which I now know of. I will update you in a bit, thanks!

Comment: OK I did my best with the comments. Question marks show the parts of which I'm not certain. Im not sure why some extra blocks are prepared on stack. Nothing is copied there and they seem to be useless. And I got lost at the end...

Comment: Oh, that is indeed what I call deep analysis. Thanks, it helped me a lot and I edited all of the comments and now I understand almost anything.

I'm using gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10). Could you please tell me if my new assumptions (1,2,3) are correct? I'm especially curious about this extra space allocated before some parameters (e.g. line +14). I spent almost all day trying to figure things out and my biggest mistake was not understanding how esp is moved after the push. I assumed it first saves the value and then moves up. Now I know I was wrong.

Comment: @Bart appended my answers to my original post (which now has become a huge wall-o-text, sorry)

Comment: Great, thanks again, that wall of text was actually a great read!

Answer (score 3):

You are first overwriting locals on the stack, which includes a saved copy of `ecx` that the compiler used to remember the stack pointer. So by the time the code gets to `0x0804846b` the value on the stack is clobbered so `ecx` is loaded with a wrong value. You can see that in your register dump, it's `0x41414141`. Next, `esp` is loaded based on `ecx`, so `esp` gets a wrong value too. Finally, the `ret` tries to pop the return address from the stack, which of course uses `esp` but that has bad value as we have seen above. Thus, crash.

Note that this code is normally only generated for `main` for alignment purposes, so you might have better luck if you stick your code into a separate function that you just call from `main`.

Comment: OK, I took some time to analyze it and I see your point. Thanks for answering.